# delete topic not working for kafka java client 2.1.0

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I want to delete a kafka topic programatically and struggling a lot to make it work. Am using below maven dependency.

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Am using KafkaAdminClient. Here is my code,

```
AdminClient admin = KafkaAdminClient.create(getProperties(configuration.getKafkaConnectionString())));

private static Properties getProperties(String kafkaConnectionString) {
    Properties config = new Properties();
    config.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaConnectionString);
    return config;
}
```

Code to delete topic:

```
public void deleteTopic(final String... topicNames) {
    admin.deleteTopics(Arrays.asList(topicNames));
    log.info("Topics '{}' deleted.", topicNames);
}
```

I have `delete.topic.enable=true` property in server.properties for kafka. There are no exception. Not sure why its not working. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Topic you are trying to delete will be still there if a producer is up and running for that topic. Can you please check this case and update?

Answer (score 2):

- Make sure producer is not using that topic.
- Since deleteTopics() method returns a future , wait for future task to complete ( In case if you are using on-demand tasks, Since main thread will not wait for future to complete if we don't do it manually.).

  ```
  public void deleteKafkaTopics(List<String> kafkaTopics) {

       DeleteTopicsResult deleteTopicsResult = kafkaAdminClient.deleteTopics(kafkaTopics);

       while (!deleteTopicsResult.all().isDone()) {

           // Wait for future task to complete

       }
   }
  ```

**Note:** If you are using windows machine you may face AccessDeniedException. Already ticket open in kafka issue board (Iam using kafka 2.1) for that fix.So I prefer to use Linux machines which is working fine with Kafka. Also don't forget to set `delete.topic.enable = true` in *config/server.properties* of Kafka brokers . For newer versions of kafka it is enabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

```java
    public static void delete(String name) {
        AdminClient client = AdminClient.create(properties());
        DeleteTopicsResult deleteTopicsResult = client.deleteTopics(Collections.singletonList(name));

        while (!deleteTopicsResult.all().isDone()) {
        }
    }
```